# Continue statement is ignored when testing a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this piece of code in a file: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/find-and-replace-text-with-javascript/

It is also replicated below:

```
function findAndReplace(searchText, replacement, searchNode) {
    // See http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/find-and-replace-text-with-javascript/

    if (!searchText || typeof replacement === 'undefined') {
        // Throw error here if you want...
        console.log('not working');
        return;
    }

    /*Set regex value*/
    var regex = typeof searchText === 'string' ?
            new RegExp(searchText, 'g') : searchText;

    /*determine child notes*/
    var childNodes = (searchNode || document.body).childNodes;
    var cnLength = childNodes.length;
    var excludes = 'html,head,style,title,link,meta,script,object,iframe';

    //walks the tree and goes to child nodes simultaneously 
    while (cnLength--) {
        var currentNode = childNodes[cnLength]; //grab last node first. work bottom to top
        if (currentNode.nodeType === 1 &&
           (excludes + ',').indexOf(currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ',') === -1) { //if node is     element node (not text) and not one of the forbidden types (blacklisted)
        //argument.callee is recursive - calling findAndReplace within itself - makes parent node  child node
            arguments.callee(searchText, replacement, currentNode);
        }


        //if node is not a text node or string node contained in current node - continue (skip over current iteration)
        if (currentNode.nodeType !== 3 || !regex.test(currentNode.data) ) {
            continue;
        } 

        console.log("1. " + currentNode.nodeType);
        console.log("2. " + regex);
        console.debug("3. " + currentNode.data);
        console.log("4. " + regex.test(currentNode.data));


        /*If there is a match - this code runs*/
        var parent = currentNode.parentNode,
            frag = (function(){
                var html = currentNode.data.replace(regex, replacement),
                    wrap = document.createElement('div'),
                    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
                 wrap.innerHTML = html;
                 while (wrap.firstChild) {
                    frag.appendChild(wrap.firstChild);
                }
                return frag;
            })();
        parent.insertBefore(frag, currentNode);
        parent.removeChild(currentNode);
    }
}
```

I'm particularly confused with the following lines:

```
 //if node is not a text node or string node contained in current node - continue (skip over current iteration)
    if (currentNode.nodeType !== 3 || !regex.test(currentNode.data) ) {
        continue;
    }
```

As far as I understand, this implies that if the current node is not a text node OR it doesn't contain the text you are searching for, you skip over the current iteration in the while loop.

However, I found that when the the function does run past the continue block, `regex.test(currentNode.data)` prints out false even if the nodeType is text (i.e. 3). Why is this the case? I thought the remainder of the while loop runs only if the text is found. (And btw, I've tested the code a few times and it does work. Just don't understand what is exactly happening.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `RegExp.test()` doesn't necessarily return the same thing when you call it multiple times. The "g" modifier in the regex causes `.test()` to keep internal track of what's the previous match it found and start from the next match if called again.

Consider this:

```js
var regex = new RegExp( 'foo', 'g'),
    data = 'foo bar';
  
console.log( regex.test( data ) );  // output: true
console.log( regex.test( data ) );  // output: false
```

That's what's happening in your code: in the if condition `regex.test(currentNode.data)` is true, and when you call it in the console.log again it's now false because the internal pointer has moved and it indicates that there are no other matches apart from the one it has already found.

If you want to log the actual value, change the code to this:

```
var dataFound = regex.test(currentNode.data);

if (currentNode.nodeType !== 3 || !dataFound ) {
    continue;
} 

// ...
console.log("4. " + dataFound );
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Makes total sense now.